# Use of paste/get in a loop-r

Tags: r, loops, get, paste

My question is so trivial, I want to paste a vector in a loop like this

```
 Mysheetlandscap <- excel_sheets("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx")

for(j in 1:length(Mysheetlandscap)){

  ClonePar <- read_excel("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx", sheet = Mysheetlandscap[j])

  x <- ClonePar$,j,[!is.na(ClonePar$MIN_CL)]  #should return the vector ClonePar$j
  }
```

So I tried

```
get(paste0("ClonePar$",j))
```

Error in get(paste0("ClonePar$", j)) : 
  object 'Cal_OCT_18_GLM$C041H' not found

What I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe `ClonePar[[3]]`.

Comment: Should iterate j in the loop

Comment: I don't recognize your syntax with `$,j,` When looping you typically need to fill an empty list `x <- list()` and then have the looping index specified when you fill it with a loop `ClonePar[j] <- read_excel("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx", sheet = Mysheetlandscap[j])`

Also is `x` outside of your loop, it isn't clear since you don't have a terminal `}`

Comment: x is inside the loop and I need to assign the vector:   ClonePar$,j,[!is.na(ClonePar$MIN_CL)] to x inside the loop

Comment: @AhmedAttia Yes, and do like EJJ says. Create `ClonePar <- list()` outside the loop. Then, inside the loop use `j` to assign values: `ClonePar[[j]] <- whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

**note:** I used `seq_along` instead of `1:length()` so that you don't get any funky output if you have an empty data frame

If you want to use a `for` loop:

```
ClonePar <- list() #create empty list

for(j in seq_along(Mysheetlandscap)){

  ClonePar[j] <- read_excel("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx", sheet = Mysheetlandscap[j])

}

ClonePar[[1]] #look the first element (a data frame) in your newly filled list
```

If you want to use the `apply` family (based on Vladimir's answer):

```
ClonePar <- lapply(seq_along(Mysheetlandscap),
                   function(j) read_excel("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx", sheet = j))
```

in the case of using `lapply` you don't have to create an empty `list` before running the vectorized operation.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand... But maybe it is what you want:

```
ClonePar <- lapply(1:length(Mysheetlandscap), function(j)
read_excel("C:/FAPSEP_Eucalyptus/FAPSEP/AHMED_GDAY/CloneParnew5_forCALIB2.xlsx", sheet = j))

j<-10
x <- ClonePar[[10]]
```